# Can I add element while using Java stream groupingby

Tags: java, java-stream, collectors, groupingby

For loop code is this.

Param : ArrayList userList

```
Map<String, User> map = new HashMap();


for (User user : userList) {
    String[] arr = user.getStringSeq().split(DELIMITER);
    String key = String.join(DELIMITER, arr[MENU_IDX], arr[GROUP_IDX]);

    if (Objects.isNull(map.get(key))) {
        Set<IOType> ioTypeSet = new HashSet<>();
        ioTypeSet.add(IOType.valueOf(arr[IO_TYPE_IDX]));
        user.setIoTypes(ioTypeSet);
        map.put(key, user);
    } else {
        map.get(key).getIoTypes().add(IOType.valueOf(arr[IO_TYPE_IDX]));
    }
}
```

and i want to modify stream

```
List<List<user>> userList = userList
        .stream()
        .collect(groupingBy(
                e -> {
                    String[] arr = e.getStringSeq().split(DELIMITER);
                    return String.join(DELIMITER, arr[0], arr[1]);
                },
                mapping(e -> {
                    IOType ioType = IOType.valueOf(e.getNavAuthSeq().split(DELIMITER)[2]);
                    User user = new User();
                    user.addIoType(ioType);
                    return user;
                }, toList())
        )).values()
        .stream()
        .toList();
```

my stream code grouping list succefully
but i want to remove same key element and put splited string
like this

```
List<List<user>> userList = userList
        .stream()
        .collect(groupingBy(
                e -> {
                    String[] arr = e.getStringSeq().split(DELIMITER);
                    return String.join(DELIMITER, arr[0], arr[1]);
                },
                mapping(e -> {
                    if (e.getIoTypes() != null) {
                        e.getIoTypes().add(IOType.NONE);
                        return null;
                    } else {
                        IOType ioType = IOType.valueOf(e.getStringSeq().split(DELIMITER)[2]);
                        UserNavAuthsLoginDTO userNavAuthsLoginDTO = new UserNavAuthsLoginDTO();
                        userNavAuthsLoginDTO.addIoType(ioType);
                        return userNavAuthsLoginDTO;
                    }
                }, toList())
        )).values()
        .stream()
        .toList();
```

but if else code doesn't work
can i resove this problem?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to discard certain elements after inside the Collector after `groupingBy`, you can wrap `mapping()` with Collector [`filtering()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#filtering(java.util.function.Predicate,java.util.stream.Collector)). It expects a `Predicate` and retains only elements for which predicate gets evaluated to `true`.

```
.collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
    e -> { },                        // classifier Function of groupingBy
    Collectors.filtering(e -> { },   // Predicate of filtering
        Collectors.mapping(e -> { }, // mapper Function of mapping
            Collectors.toList())
    )
))
```

***Note** that there's a difference between using `filter()` operation and Collector `filtering()`. Imagine a scenario when **all** elements mapped to a particular Key don't pass the predicate. In this case, the entry with this Key **would be present** in the resulting Map (and its Value would be an empty list). And if you apply `filter()` in the stream - there wouldn't be such entry.*

Alternatively, if it's **not** important to filter out elements after the grouping phase, you can use `filter()` operation, that would be a **preferred** way in such case.

Also, worth to point out that you're performing *side-effects* on the mutable function parameter inside `mapping()` (*to put it simple, anything that a function doesn't besides computing its resulting value is a side-effect*). I'm not claiming that it will break things somehow, but it's definitely not very clean.